# Get class value and text from qualifying span tags in html document

Tags: php, arrays, dom, xpath, html-parsing

Please help me with the following pattern for preg_match_all

How to change my pattern to get the desired output?

In a string search for tags with a class name like '`email_`' (`email_` OR `email_p_12` OR `email_22` OR `email_xx`)

get the text between tags `<span class=" xx email_xx xx "> THE EMAIL ADDRESS </span>`

get the classname starting with 'email_'

This is my pattern : `$pattern = '~<span class=\"((.*?)*)*(email_(.*?))?(.*?)\">(.*?)</span>~';`

What I need is an Array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mail] => labore@et.de
            [class] => email_p_14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mail] => esse@cillum.de
            [class] => email_p_22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mail] => anim@id.de
            [class] => email_ 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mail] => laboris@nisi.de
            [class] => email_
        )

)
```

File:

```
<?php
    
$string = '
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut

    <span class=" red email_p_14">labore@et.de</span>

dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea consequat. 
Duis aute irure in reprehenderit in voluptate velit

    <span class="email_p_22">esse@cillum.de</span>

dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit

    <span class="blue email_ green">anim@id.de</span>

laborum. Donec elementum ligula.
Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 

    <span class="blue email_ green black">laboris@nisi.de</span>

aliquip ex ea consequat. 
</p>';


/* Looking for these:

<span class=" red email_p_14">labore@et.de</span>
<span class="email_p_22">esse@cillum.de</span>
<span class="blue email_ green">anim@id.de</span>
<span class="blue email_ green black">laboris@nisi.de</span>

*/


$pattern = '~<span class=\"((.*?)*)*(email_(.*?))?(.*?)\">(.*?)</span>~';

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $m);

$clean_array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', $m));

ksort($clean_array);
$output = Array();

foreach($clean_array as $row) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val){
        $output[$key][]=$val;
    }
}
print("<pre>".print_r($output,true)."</pre>");
```

This is what i get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => labore@et.de
            [1] =>  red email_p_14
            [2] => labore@et.de
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => esse@cillum.de
            [1] => email_
            [2] => p_22
            [3] => esse@cillum.de
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => anim@id.de
            [1] => blue email_ green
            [2] => anim@id.de
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => laboris@nisi.de
            [1] => blue email_ green black
            [2] => laboris@nisi.de
        )

)
```

What I need is an Array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mail] => labore@et.de
            [class] => email_p_14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mail] => esse@cillum.de
            [class] => email_p_22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mail] => anim@id.de
            [class] => email_ 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mail] => laboris@nisi.de
            [class] => email_
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: We do not parse html with regex.

Comment: You are aware that you have the upvote privilege, right?  If you ever find any correct answers to be helpful you can thank them by upvoting each answer.  This also signals to future researchers that you recommend the advice in the answer.  I don't need any more points and neither does thefourthbird, but you should understand the tools that you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse html with DOMDocument and XPath.  Once you have targeted the appropriate nodes, dig in and extract the data, then push the new subarrays into the result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cOgB4))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$result = [];
foreach ($xpath->query("//span[starts-with(@class, 'email_') or contains(@class, ' email_')]") as $span) {
    $result[] = [
         'mail' => $span->nodeValue,
         'class' => preg_replace(
             '~.*\b(email_\S*).*~',
             '$1',
             $span->getAttribute('class')
         )
    ];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'mail' => 'labore@et.de',
    'class' => 'email_p_14',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'mail' => 'esse@cillum.de',
    'class' => 'email_p_22',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'mail' => 'anim@id.de',
    'class' => 'email_',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'mail' => 'laboris@nisi.de',
    'class' => 'email_',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working as required. I think this answer covers the question best. Also very compact, clear and elegant.

Comment: Nice solution, that deserves some more credit. ++

Answer (score 1):

For the class value you use this pattern `((.*?)*)*(email_(.*?))?(.*?)` which uses a combination of repeating capture groups where all is actually optional.

For the email address you use `(.*?)` which matches any char non greedy and does not match an email like pattern.

You can make use of named capture groups to get the keys `mail` and `class`:

```
<span[^<>]*\bclass="[^"]*(?<class>email_[^\s"]*)[^"]*">\h*(?<mail>[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)\h*<\/span>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3QvZvA/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/mGHR9)

In the result, remove the numerical keys:

```
$re = '`<span[^<>]*\bclass="[^"]*(?<class>email_[^\s"]*)[^"]*">\h*(?<mail>[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+)\h*<\/span>`';
$str = '<span class=" xx email_p_14 xx "> labore@et.de </span>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
print_r(array_filter($matches[0], function ($k) { return !is_numeric($k); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [class] => email_p_14
    [mail] => labore@et.de
)
```

---

What you could also do is look into [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), find the spans that have a classname starting with email_ and then match the value of that span for an email address like pattern.

Then you can build your array with the keys and values.

For example

```
$str = '<span class=" xx email_p_14 xx "> labore@et.de </span>';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$doc = new DOMXPath($dom);

$items = $doc->query("//span[contains(@class, 'email_')]");

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $class = array_filter(explode(' ', $item->getAttribute('class')), function($x) {
        return substr( $x, 0, 6 ) === "email_";
    });
    print_r($class);
    echo $item->nodeValue;
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => email_p_14
)
 labore@et.de
```

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/LTAgk)